# Both builtin and pyopensssl doesn't work with cherrypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, cherrypy, pyopenssl

I secured my cherrypy webservice weeks ago on my old pc. Then i had problems so i exported my codes on a new one. Before that everything worked great. Now when i use builtin ssl my webpage stops to respond because cherrypy doesn't respond (even in the terminal, it works again only when i modify the code) after some requests. If i use pyopenssl everything works great in my pc. If i try to connect from another pc or from my smartphone/tablet i get this error:

```
    "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1540, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantWriteError() 
    OpenSSL.SSL.WantWriteError
```

It comes after i try to return images, even small like the website icon.
Here is my code, i followed cherrypy documentation:

```
    # MAIN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = {
            '/':{
                    'request.dispatch':cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
                    'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),
                    'tools.sessions.on':True,
                    'tools.sessions.secure' : True,
                    'tools.sessions.httponly' : True,
                    'tools.secureheaders.on' : True
                    
                },
            '/favicon.ico':
            {
                'tools.staticfile.on': True,
                'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + '/favicon.ico'
            },

            '/js':{
                    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                    'tools.staticdir.dir':'./js'
                },
            '/css':{
                    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                    'tools.staticdir.dir':'./css'
                },
            '/css/Resources':{
                    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                    'tools.staticdir.dir':'./css/Resources'
                }
    }
    porta = 443 #porta usata
    ip = get_ip() #funzione che prende l'ip del pc

    #inizializzo cherrypy
    cherrypy.tree.mount(SleepRepository(), '/', conf)

        # if hasattr(app, 'toolboxes'):
        # # CherryPy 3.1+
        #   app.toolboxes['secureheaders'] = secureheaders.newauthtools

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': ip })      
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': porta}) 
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.max_request_body_size' : 35971520000}) #aumento il massimo in MB che posso ricevere
    cherrypy.server.ssl_module = 'pyopenssl'
    cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate = "cert.pem"
    cherrypy.server.ssl_private_key = "privkey.pem"
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

About the error i find a thread that suggest to modify a line of a library but it doesn't work the same... Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I had the same problem serving images and found the answer here: https://github.com/cherrypy/cheroot/issues/245

It should be fixed in newer versions of cheroot, but a patch is given. In makefile.py replace the method BufferedWriter._flush_unlocked() with:

```
import OpenSSL
def _flush_unlocked(self):
self._checkClosed('flush of closed file')
while self._write_buf:
    try:
        # ssl sockets only except 'bytes', not bytearrays
        # so perhaps we should conditionally wrap this for perf?
        n = self.raw.write(self._write_buf)
    except io.BlockingIOError as e:
        n = e.characters_written
    except (OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError,OpenSSL.SSL.WantWriteError, OpenSSL.SSL.WantX509LookupError) as e:
        n = 0
    del self._write_buf[:n]

BufferedWriter._flush_unlocked = _flush_unlocked
```

The same thread had another suggestion, modifying a single line, that didn't work for me. You may have found that same suggestion, but this one did work for me.

Comment: Thank you but I moved to flask because i needed to end my project... But i think this may be useful in any case  :)